# How to write data to multiple files using arrays of pointers of file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

This is my code which I have written so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() 

int main() 
{ 
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2; 
    char filename[100], c;
    char quit[4] = "exit";
    // char *filearray[100];
    char filearray[100][14];
    FILE **originalfilearray;
    int counter = 0;


    //Copy part
    while(1){
        printf("Enter the filename to open for reading \n"); 
        scanf("%s", filename);

        fptr1 = fopen(filename, "r"); 
        if (fptr1 == NULL) 
        {   
            break;

            printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename); 
            exit(0); 
        }

        strcpy(filearray[counter], filename);
        originalfilearray[counter] = fptr1;
        counter+=1;
    }

    //Paste part
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the filename to open for writing for file %s\n", filearray[i]); 
        scanf("%s", filename);

        fptr2 = fopen(filename, "w");

        // Read contents from file 
        c = fgetc(fptr2);
        while (c != EOF)
        {
            fputc(c, fptr2);
            c = fgetc(originalfilearray[i]); 
        }
        printf("\nContents copied to %s\n", filename); 
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I run the paste code the file is created but no content is pasted.

I have already tried reading many post regarding array of pointers of file. Some suggested to create originalfilearray variable with a single pointer some with double.

The major problem I guess is with the copy part.

Can someone please help me with the part where I need to copy the data of multiple files in the originalfilearray variable

Thank You

Comment: Some observations, 1) `FILE **originalfilearray;` has no memory allocated for it, perhaps it should be `FILE *originalfilearray[14];` although an array of `struct`s is often better than separate arrays. 2) `char c` should be `int c`. 3) `char quit[4] = "exit"` (which you don't use) lacks a string terminator. 4) `c = fgetc(fptr2);` is incorrect - that's the file you are writing to.

Comment: ...and because you start by trying to read from the output file, the loop `while (c != EOF)` will never iterate.

Comment: Can you mention the changes I should make for reading the input file and pasting it in the output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from not allocating memory for originalfilearray, which other user explained, here are some things you are doing wrong

In

```
c = fgetc(fptr2);
```

You are trying to get character from an empty file you just opened in

```
fptr2 = fopen(filename, "w");
```

what you should be doing is starting a file pointer `fptr` and opening

```
FILE *fptr=fopen(filearray[i], "r");
```

and then copying content into it with

```
while ((c = fgetc(fptr))!= EOF)
        {
            fputc(c, fptr2);
        }
```